# Upgrading from netty 3.2.x to 3.3x and Unsafe

Tags: netty

actually I'm using netty 3.2.7 in a custom streaming server project. I'm trying upgrading to netty 3.3.x but I encountered problems related to "Unsafe".

I have a handler that subclass "ChunkedWriteHandler" and another class that subclass "ChunkedInput" in order to implement chunked http data trasfer to the clients.

After upgrading to 3.3.x my code breaks with the following message:

```
Invalid memory access of location 0x15e47da eip=0x708666
```

Looking at the source code I can see that now the buffer used inside ChunkedWriteHandler uses Unsafe to optimize some operations but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong (for causing an invalid memory access) and how to fix this issue.

Can some netty guru help me to understand and fix my problem?

Thanks,
Rocco

Comment: This sounds more like a jdk bug. What java version are you using ?

Comment: I've made other tests. On my primary dev machine, a 32 bit mac os 10.5 with the latest java 5, i experience the issue reported above. On my notebook, a 64 bit mac os 10.7 with the latest java 6 everything seems working properly.

Comment: Yeah like I said it looks like a jdk bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In netty 3.4.1.Final its now possible to disable unsafe via "-Dorg.jboss.netty.tryUnsafe=false"